# Can't run binary executable on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, binary

I get the following error: `./cataclysm: command not found` when trying to run this executable on a Linux server over SSH.

When I run `ldd cataclysm`, I get:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf7759000)
liblua5.1.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblua5.1.so.0 (0xf7716000)
libncursesw.so.5 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.5 (0xf76e6000)
libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0xf76c6000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf75d2000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf75a6000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7588000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf73de000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf73d8000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf775a000)
```

Is everything ok here?

It's a 64-bit server and I installed `ia32-libs`, as I thought this might be the issue. But it's still not working.

Output for `file`:

```
cataclysm: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x401728ba70c6dede81053dd2578dbe358f27b29c, stripped
```

output for `ls -lh`:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 userx6342 userx6342 7.0M Mar  5 11:28 cataclysm
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your binary isn't executable, as indicated by the `ls -lh` output. To fix this,

```
chmod 755 cataclysm
```

Then you should be able to run

```
./cataclysm
```

given that `ldd` shows you have all the required libraries already.